# how to colors empty cells

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

it works good but he doesn't take the last line of the tab

can u please help me to find my errors !

```
         Dim c As Range
```

`Dim MaPlage As Range`

```
   For q = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set MaPlage = Range("A:H, J:R").Rows(q)
 For Each c In MaPlage.Cells
If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Interior.Color = vbYellow

If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 31).Value) = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" _
     And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MaPlage, "") = 0 Then
    Select Case UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 14).Value)
        Case "INA_CIN"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 42).Value = "XX"
    End Select
End If

Next c
```

`Next q`

Comment: You have two areas in your range - `A:H` and `J:R`.  `maplage.Rows(1).address` will naturally use the first area, while `maplage.Areas(2).Rows(1).address` will return J:R.  The Union method `Set MaPlage = Union(Range("A:H"), Range("J:R"))` will still return two areas.  Maybe better to set a reference to A:R?

Comment: can i use that for more than 2 or three areas

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i tried that but is still takes only the first area  `Set MaPlage = Union(Range("A:H"), Range("J:R")).Rows(q)`

Comment: Some commands like Row don't allow for ranges with more than one area. You could try instead with: `Intersect(Range("A:H, J:R"),Rows(q))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** updated to show how to highlight empty cells

```
Dim MaPlage As Range, c As Range

Set MaPlage = Sheet1.Range(Replace("A#:H#,J#:R#", "#", q)) 

For Each c In MaPlage.Cells '<<EDIT2 to remove extra space
    If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Interior.Color = vbRed
Next c
```

EDIT2:

```
Sub TT()

    Const S As String = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite"

    Dim MaPlage As Range, c As Range, rw As Range
    Dim q As Integer, blanks As Long

       For q = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

           Set rw = Sheet1.Rows(q)
           Set MaPlage = rw.Range("A1:H1,J1:R1")
           blanks = 0
           For Each c In MaPlage.Cells
               If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
                  c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                  blanks = blanks + 1
               End If
           Next c

           If CStr(rw.Cells(31).Value) = S And blanks = 0 Then
               Select Case UCase(rw.Cells(14).Value)
                Case "INA_CIN"
                    rw.Cells(42).Value = "XX"
                End Select
           End If

    Next q
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you  so much @Tim Williams

Comment: I would like to know how to color if one or more  of these cells are empty

Comment: Hey @Tim Williams i tried it it dosn't really work     `Dim g As Integer      
 Dim MaPlage As Range, c As Range
 Dim q As Integer
 For q = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Set MaPlage = Sheet1.Range(Replace("A#:H#,J#:R#", "#", q))
 For Each c In MaPlage .Cells
 If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Interior.Color = vbRed
 If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 31).Value) = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" _
 And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MaPlage, "") = 0 Then`

Comment: `Select Case UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 14).Value)
 Case "INA_CIN"
 ActiveSheet.Cells(q, 42).Value = "XX"
 End Select
 End If
 Next c
 Next q`

Comment: *Update your question* and add your code there: code in comments is impossible to read.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank u for trying to help me out but it doesn't work really good , i fixed another code ( i updated the code on the top) but the problem he does not take the last row , he stopped always on the one before the last row of the tab