# Need logic for checking range in formula

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with logic. I have about 1000 rows of data where formulas were entered to calculate subtotals and totals. The nature of the formulas require each respective range to be correct. The correct range is determined by data in column C (please see illustration). For the most part, the ranges (and in turn the formula) are correct. But I have reason to believe a handful are not.

I can check them all manually or I can ask SO for help ^_^ My current thought is to loop column A and at every `Subtotal`, dump the rows counted so far into column V and pull the rows in the formula from column G into column W then compare V and W.

But what do I do when I reach a `Total`? My current thought would become cumbersome. Is there a better way? All the highlighted `0`s between columns `i:u` need to be tested as well.

I will entertain solution to replace all formulas from scratch as well.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, I don't need a single line of code. Just logic/architecture. I was also thinking perhaps building checks into column V? A formula that sums `i:t` and subtracts `u`? But that doesn't ensure accuracy if ALL `i:u` is bad and the same XD

Comment: And you are not using Excel's built in subtotals because...? Just a question as I think this through

Comment: Because I didn't build this spreadsheet. Just checking it ;_; Edit: there's also a lot of formatting I took out. The actual thing looks like a report XD

Comment: Actually, that's not a bad idea. Build a new book and run subtotals then compare...I would need to manually fake data though XD

Comment: You could strip the row range from the formula string then compare that to the to row string that you build via vba using loops that resets on each "subtotal" or "total".  Putting the string("Start row Number:End row Number") in another cell.

Comment: That sounds like my idea? but to capture range for total is a pain XD Edit: I was hoping for some brilliance like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397041/selecting-multiple-ranges-in-excel-vba#33398237) XD

Comment: To get the row range from a formula I use this `Replace(Left(Split(Selection.Formula, "(")(1), Len(Split(Selection.Formula, "(")(1)) - 1), "A", "")` Where "A" is the column that the formula calls.

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking it. Let me start coding.

Comment: Boo for use of `select` =P

Comment: I figured you are smart enough to replace it with the appropriate variable. Don't go proving me wrong :)

Comment: Pfft flagging and reporting you for using select. I had such high regards for you. NO MORE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I wanted to run it by you as an idea.
This example will put the totals from column G into Column Z.

Anyway, check it out, if you don't like it, I'll get rid of it.
You can add another line or make up a loop to get all the columns total.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim RangeArea As Range

    For Each RangeArea In Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas

        Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Application.Sum(RangeArea.Offset(, 4))

    Next RangeArea

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah niiiice. Yea, I think easiest way to check is to fake data.

Comment: Sigh faking data is actually the hardest part XD